# How to publish a product with more than 50 dynamic properties

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

In Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM (Customer Engagement) - Sales, we got the following error when trying to publish a product that has more than 50 dynamic properties.

> Error (code: 0x8008100d):
> This product can't be published because it has too many dynamic properties. A product in your organization can't have more than 50 dynamic properties

Where can we change that limit?

More info: it works fine to publish products that has less than 50 dynamic properties by sending patch http request with the following json

```
{
    "statecode" : 0 ,
    "statuscode" : 1 
};
```

to the following url with Product GUID:

```
https://YOUR-RESOURCE_URL/api/data/v9.1/products('YOUR-PRODUCT-GUID')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of product properties that can be associated to a draft product family record is determined by the following organization setting: **Organization.MaximumDynamicPropertiesAllowed**. The number comes into effect when you publish a child product record or bundle under a product family that the properties are attached to, and not at the time when you attach the properties to a draft product family record.

See [Create and manage product families, products, bundles, and product properties - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/create-manage-product-families-products-bundles-product-properties?view=op-9-1).

Comment: Hi, does that also apply products without product families?

Comment: For products not associated with a product family, that is, products that don’t have a parent product family record assigned to them, you can create them directly in an Active state by setting the Organization.CreateProductsWithoutParentInActiveState attribute to 1 (true). By default, this attribute is set to 0 (false) for a fresh installation of Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement and to 1 (true) if you’re upgrading from a previous version of Customer Engagement

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer at Microsoft Dynamics 365 Sales Forum:

The setting can be changed from the following path in on-prem version:
Setting -> Administration -> System Setting -> Sales (tab)

I checked out a similar path at Sales - cloud version and it works!
Advanced Settings -> Setting -> Administration -> System Setting -> Sales (tab)

[image: Sales Tab]

Link to the answer:
https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/dynamics-365-for-sales-forum/428961/publishing-product-with-more-than-50-dynamic-properties

I have also ensured that it works to post such products through WebApi after activating that setting.